# Tree without cofinal branches and with levels of bounded size

Tags: set-theory, infinitary-combinatorics

My question is: let's say that a tree T has no cofinal branch and has all levels of size $< \mu$. Can we prove (in ZFC) that the set of branches of T has cardinality $\leq \mu$? I have a very strong intuition that it is so, but I can't come up with a proof (or a counterexample).

Answer (score 1):

No.

Suppose that $T$ is a normal Aronszajn tree (so any point has splitting successors) and $2^{\aleph_0}>\aleph_1$. Then there are no cofinal branches, but easily due to splitting at any successor point, any limit stage will have continuum many branches, of which only countably many are allowed to be realised and extended.

Comment: But in that case, don't you also have that the cardinality of nodes at any limit stage is the continuum? What are $\mu$ and the hight of the tree in your example?

Comment: No, Aronszajn trees are exactly trees of height $\omega_1$, where each level is countable, and there are no branches.

Comment: But if you also require that at each successor level you have a splitting for each element, shouldn't level $\omega$ already have continuum many elements?

Comment: No. Because I didn't say that the tree is **closed**. If it is closed, it will have a cofinal branch, that's just applying the axiom of choice.

Comment: I see. I was thinking of a general tree as closed. My mistake.

Comment: If the tree is closed, then there is a cofinal branch. So by saying there is none, you already gave up on that property. Adding to it that the levels are small will simply mean that at limit stages "most branches" will not have a continuation. And indeed, with the exception of $\aleph_1$, ZFC is generally unable to prove that there even trees of height $\mu$ without cofinal branches and with small levels (at least for regular $\mu$).

Comment: but must the set of branches that "have a maximum level" (I don't know if there is a term for this but I hope it is clear) have size $\leq \mu$?

Comment: You're talking about branches with a maximal point? Yes. If the tree, as a whole, as size $\mu$, there are at most $\mu$ points which are maximal. This is fairly straightforward to see, I think you'll agree with me here. :-)

Comment: No, the tree as a whole might have a larger size, I didn't specify the height. Anyway, what I mean is that the number of branches in your example can surpass $\mu$ but almost all of them "die" anyway before reaching a certain limit level $< ht(T)$ How many of them can avoid this behaviour?